# Overloading and assignment operator

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading

I came across this question:

> X *= y is an example of
>
> - Arithmetic assignment operations
> - Assignment operator
> - Overloading arithmetic operations with assignment operator
> - All of the above

I expected the answer to be "Assignment operator", but the answer is given as "Overloading arithmetic operations with assignment operator".

Can someone explain how we are doing operator overloading in the `*=` operator?

Comment: Did it give any context, such as a definition of the type of  `X` and/or `y`? Without that, the question is basically unanswerable.

Comment: `*=` is a *compound assignment operator*.  For arithmetic types, it performs BOTH multiplication AND assignment, where `X *= Y` is equivalent to `X = X * Y`.  For user-defined types, it is an overridable operator, so its actual behavior depends on the type's implementation.

Comment: For an example of "Overloading arithmetic operations with assignment operator", write a `Fractions` class and overload `operator*=` or `operator+=`.